# Add text inside the tags from a string Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field and enter a XHTML code in it it returns me the output the modified code, for example I digit in the following input:

```
<label> Text <label>
<p> RESULT TEXT </p>
<label> Text <label>
 <p> RESULT TEXT </p>
<label> Text <label>
 <p> RESULT TEXT </p>
<label> Text <label>
 <p> RESULT TEXT </p>
```

I need to add the following word "Box" inside the tag `<p>` and leave only the first letter in uppercase and the rest in lowercase. Getting your bottom line this way:

```
<label> Text <label>
<p> Result text box </p>
<label> Text <label>
 <p> Result text box </p>
<label> Text <label>
 <p> Result text box </p>
<label> Text <label>
 <p> Result text box </p>
```

I'm trying to do this using the following code:

```
var code = $('textarea[name=message]').val();
        /* prevent the creation of multiple output-blocks if someone clicks on the submit-button more than once */
        if ($('#output').length < 1) {
            $("body").append('<h2>Output</h2><textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>');
        }

        code = code.find(p).text("box");
        code = code..replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});



        $('#output').val(code);
```

Comment: two dots in code..replace

Comment: what is this for "code.find(p).text("box");"? Can you share jsfiddle for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues:

- your `label` tags are wrongly closed (*you forgot the `/`*)
- your `code` variable is a string and not a jquery object so you cannot perform `find` on it.
- you have a syntax error with the `code..replace` (*double dot*)
- in `.find(p)`, `p` is not defined. What you want is to pass a string so you must wrap it in quotes. `.find('p')`

Fixing all those issues you end with something like this

```
var code = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

/* prevent the creation of multiple output-blocks if someone clicks on the submit-button more than once */
if ($('#output').length < 1) {
    $("body").append('<h2>Output</h2><textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>');
}

// create a jquery object out of the code
var livehtml = $('<div/>', {
    html: code
});

// find the <p> elements and alter their html
livehtml.find('p').append("box").html(function (idx, currentHtml) {
    return currentHtml.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + currentHtml.substr(1).toLowerCase();
});

$('#output').val(livehtml.html());
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/UpYgA/

Comment: That's what I need! Only need to leave the First letter Uppercase and lowercase on the other within the <p> tag: D Thanks

Comment: @pegoj, You need to `trim` the whitespace because your first character is a space. Updated demo at http://jsfiddle.net/UpYgA/1/

Comment: @pegoj why ? what is happening ? (*it should work just fine on IE8, excapt that tags will be in all capitals because that is how IE8 stores this info*)